# 301 Redirect www and other subdomains in a subdirectory to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

301 Redirect by htaccess **all URLs** with **any subdomains** in a **subdirectory** to **non-www**

Examples:

```
https://www.example.com/forum
```

to `https://example.com/forum`

```
https://anysubdomains.example.com/forum
```

to `https://example.com/forum`

```
https://www.example.com/forum/anysubdiretory
```

to `https://example.com/forum/anysubdirectory`

```
https://anydubdomains.example.com/forum/anysubdiretory
```

to `https://example.com/forum/anysubdirectory`

The code below works only for www but how to make it work for all subdomains:

```
RewriteEngine on

#the directory the rule should apply to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum/  [NC]
#check if the host  string starts with "www"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
#redirect all www urls to non-www
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any subdomains including `www` , you can use a regex pattern that matches everything . Your RewruteCondition currently only matches a `www` subdomain , replace it with a wildcard match `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]` .

You can use the following :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this new redirect.